# Confusion regarding definition of $F^\infty$ in Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*

Tags: linear-algebra

In his linear algebra book, Sheldon Axler defines the set of all sequences of elements of $F$ as:

$$F^\infty = \{(x_1, x_2, \ldots): x_j \in F\text{ for } j = 1, 2, \ldots\}.$$

He also says:

> Sometimes we will use the word list without specifying its length. Remember, however, that by definition each list has a finite length that is a nonnegative integer, so that an object that looks like $(x_1,x_2, \ldots)$,
>   which might be said to have infinite length, is not a list.

I feel like there's a contradiction here. If we went by what's said in the quote we could(?) conclude that the elements of $F^\infty$ are finite in length.

Please, elaborate on this.

Comment: I think this is just distinguishing between *lists* as being finite and *sequences* as being (countably) infinite.

Comment: He defines vectors spaces like $F^n$ in terms of lists, so I am not sure he's making that distinction.

Answer (score 3):

There is no contradiction here because of the following. The quoted portion says that an object of the form
$$
(x_1,x_2,\dots)
$$
is not a list, by the definition of a list (a list must have finite length). The definition of $F^\infty$ is given as
$$
F^\infty = \{ (x_1,x_2,\dots) : x_j \in F \text{ for } j = 1,2,\dots \}.
$$

---

The quoted part ***does not*** say that
$$
(x_1,x_2,\dots)
$$
represents a list of length $n$ for some arbitrary length $n$. Also, the definition of $F^\infty$ is ***not***
$$
F^\infty = \{ (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) : x_j \in F \text{ for } j = 1,\dots,n, \text{ and $n$ arbitrary positive integer}\}.
$$

---

Perhaps you were confused with one or the other aspect of the definitions as in above. Basically, although $F^n$ is defined as the set of lists of length $n$, $F^\infty$ is not defined in terms of lists and is instead defined in terms of objects of the form
$$
(x_1,x_2,\dots).
$$